# Returning the pointer address of a value within an array

Tags: c++

I am required to find the address of a matching value in an array, as stated in the following question:

> This function searches length elements of array list for the value target. It returns the index where target was found, or -1 if the value is not present.
>
> ```
> int find(int target, int list[], int length) {
>   for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
>       if (list[i] == target) return i;
>   }
>   return -1;
> }
> ```
>
> Rewrite the function using pointers to indicate the search range. The search should begin by examining the element at start and end at stop without examining that value. The return value should be a pointer to the location of the target value or a null pointer if the values is not present.

The code I have is here, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* find(int target, int* start, int* stop)
{    
    while(start <= stop)
    {
        if (*start == target)
        {
            return start;
        }    
        start++;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    int someArray[] = {3,10,19,7,3,45,123,4,9,89};

    int start = *someArray[0];
    int stop = *someArray[9];

    cout << *find(19, start, stop);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The start and stop pointers should be initialized appropriately:

```
int* start = &someArray[0];
int* stop = &someArray[9];
```

You also want to know the `index` of the array where the `target` is at (and not the `target` itself), so you have to change the line:

```
cout << *find(19, start, stop);
```

to

```
cout << find(19, start, stop) - someArray ;
```

In this way, you will not be in the danger of accessing the `nullptr`.
If a negative value is printed, it would mean that the `target` is not in `someArray`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::find` and `std::distance`, to get the index of the value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const int someArray [] = {3,10,19,7,3,45,123,4,9,89};
    const int len = sizeof(someArray) / sizeof(int);

    const auto it = std::find(&someArray[0], &someArray[len], 19);

    std::cout << std::distance(&someArray[0], it);
    return 0;
}
```

or if you use `std::array` or another std container you can use `.begin()` and `.end()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const std::array<int,10> someArray = {3,10,19,7,3,45,123,4,9,89};     

    const auto it = std::find(someArray.begin(), someArray.end(), 19);

    std::cout << std::distance(someArray.begin(),it);
    return 0;
}
```

You can use

```
const auto start = someArray.begin() + value;
```

and likewise `stop` to norrow the search area of `someArray`.

Comment: Why switch to a vector?  `std::find` works just fine with a regular array.

Answer (score 0):

Your function find() requires the 'addresses' of the start/end of the array, but you're assigning the 'value' of the start/end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `start` and `stop` variables need to be pointers. For example:

```
int *start = &someArray[0];
int *stop = &someArray[9];
```

And be careful by using the line

```
cout << *find(19, start, stop);
```

with another value that is not in the array. This results in an access violation because you try to derefence a `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

An asterisk (*) dereferences a pointer. That is, it gives you the value at the address. An ampersand (&) gets the pointer to a value. The start and stop pointers should be the addresses of the first and last values.

If you turn on more warnings, the compiler might tell you that you are dereferencing something that is not a pointer and you are passing `int` values to the function where pointers are expected.

```
int *start = &someArray[0];
int *stop = &someArray[9];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++11 (which you should), then `std::end` is specialized for arrays.

You can avoid either having to hard-code the array size as the magic number `9`, or writing out the `sizeof(someArray)/sizeof(someArray[0])` incantation (which is itself at least better than hardcoding the type in your sizeof expression).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const int someArray [] = {3,10,19,7,3,45,123,4,9,89};

    const auto it = std::find(std::begin(someArray), std::end(someArray), 19);

    std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(someArray), it);
    return 0;
}
```

If you *do* want to use your custom `find` function, note that `begin` and `end` just return pointers in this case anyway, and `it` will also be a pointer in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have stated, your `start` and `stop` variables need to be `int*` pointers, and you need to use the `&` address operator instead of the `*` dereference operator to obtain those pointers:

```
int *start = &someArray[0];
int *stop = &someArray[9];
```

However, there is another, more subtle, bug in your code.  As the documented requirement states:

> The search should begin by examining the element at `start` and **end at `stop` without examining that value**.

But your code is examining the value at `stop`.  This is because you are using the `<=` operator, when you should be using the `<` operator instead:

```
//while (start <= stop)
while (start < stop)
```

Making this change then creates a new bug in your `main()` code.  `someArray[9]` is the last element in the array (89).  After making the above change, this element will no longer be compared when using `someArray[9]` for the `stop` pointer.  So, if you were to call `find(89, start, stop)`, it would return `nullptr` instead of the address of `someArray[9]`.  As such, you need to set `stop` to the address of `someArray[10]` instead:

```
int *stop = &someArray[10];
```

This is on par with how STL algorithms works with iterator ranges (and raw pointers are also iterators).  The ending iterator always represents "1-past-the-end" and is never dereferenced, only used for comparing when the starting iterator reaches the ending iterator.  The C++ standard also explicitly allows obtaining a pointer to "1-past-the-end" of an array, for similar reasons.

With that said, try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

int* find(int target, int* start, int* stop)
{    
    while (start < stop)
    {
        if (*start == target)
        {
            return start;
        }    
        ++start;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    int someArray[] = {3,10,19,7,3,45,123,4,9,89};

    int *start = &someArray[0];
    int *stop = &someArray[10];

    std::cout << "Enter a number to find: ";

    int num;
    std::cin >> num;

    int *found = find(num, start, stop);
    if (found)
        std::cout << "Found at index " << static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(found - start);
    else
        std::cout << "Not found";

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/uHogQF)